# Javascript - Show name and get id in Typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead.js

I'm using Typeahead in my html. I want to show region name and get region id . but I both show and get region ID . how to solve it ?

**myFile,js:**

```
.
.
.
var regions = response.data.result;
console.log(regions);
```

Here is screenshot of result in Inspect element:
[image]

I want to show regionName in my typeahead and get regionId.

```
            var regionValue = regions.map(function(result) {
                return result.regionId;
            });
        $scope.autocomplete = $('.the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
                hint: false,
                highlight: false,
                minLength: 1,
                datumTokenizer:  true
            },{
                name: 'states',
                source: substringMatcher(regionValue),
                templates:{
                    empty:[
                        '<div class="empty-message"> No result...</div>'
                    ]
                }
            })


var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;
    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];
    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });
    cb(matches);
  };
};
```

Actually I want to show regionName and get regionId. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that what you want is that in the dropdown regionName be displayed and when you select the item you obtain the id, if so you could do the following to show only regionName do this

```
$scope.autocomplete = $('.the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: false,
            highlight: false,
            minLength: 1,
            datumTokenizer:  true
        },{
            name: 'states',
            source: substringMatcher(regionValue),
            templates:{
                empty:[
                     '<div class="empty-message"> No result...</div>'
                ],
                suggestion: function(data) {    
                       return '<p> + data.regionName + '</p>';
                    }
            }
        })
```

and to get id of element when selected items do you do this

```
$('.the-basics .typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj,datum, name) {
   //put here you code after selected item
   datum.regionId
})
```

Look at the [docs typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)